# Git remote repository using ssh in Windows 10 - Is there any way to make it work flawlessly?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, client-certificates

I am using Windows 10 PRO and have set up ssh for my remote repository in git. My largest hurdle is that the password cannot be stored between sessions.

I can get the password to cache using ssh-agent and ssh-add for **one** session, but not when i start a new command line window (or terminal in VS code).

Is there any way to make ssh authentication work flawlessly in Windows 10 - similar to the macOS option in `~/.ssh/config`

```
UseKeychain yes
```

Kind regards /K